# Excel, Add auto Sequence number

Tags: excel, sequence

I need to ad the next sequence number in Column A automatically when I fill enter the next value in Column B. This sounds confused. Just see the snap so you will get the clear picture[image].

This should be done without usual dragging option. Is there any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the Value of A1 equal to 1 and then from the A2 use the formula:

```
=IF(B3<>"",A2+1," ")
```

Drag this formula for the whole column.

In my solution I have a drag, but it is to define the formula for each of the fields. (I'm not sure if is this you are trying to avoid when you say

> without the usual dragging option

)

Comment: This is what i noted. After read your answer I realize how simple it is. But didn't thought it by myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this using macros. Formula will increase the file size and processing time.

Right click on the sheet name on sheet tab-->select view code-->paste below code--> save file as macro enabled workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo step
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Value <> "" Then
Target.Offset(0, -1) = Target.Row - 1
End If

Exit Sub

step:
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without using macro and formula:

1. Type first 2 value to the cell to establish the pattern
2. highlight the cell range
3. Under Home tag -> select Fill -> choose Series
4. Follow the image and Select OK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your table to a List ("Table") and use a formula for the first column, that formula will "auto-extend" as new values are typed in under "Item"

[image]